# Find parameters value of specific method with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to find all of the occurrences of a method call.

Example: 
I have a class like this:

```cs
public class Foo
{
   public string Bar(string firstParam, string secondParam){}
}
```

What I need to do is to open a solution and find all of the usages of the method Bar in the class Foo. Now for each usage, I want to retrieve the value of the first parameter when it was passed as a string.

So if I have this line somewhere in my code:

```cs
foo.Bar("some value", "something else")
```

Then I should retrieve "some value".

Now if I have:

```cs
foo.Bar(someProperty, "something else")
```

Then I should ignore it.

I did find lots of sources during my researches but I can't seem to find a way that does actually work.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to do this with Roslyn or not.  I know in VS you can right click a method and choose `Find all references` or with hotkeys you can hold `Ctrl` and press `K` then `R` to do the same thing.  It doesn't get as details as you're searching for but you could adapt that logic into your own extension for VS pretty easily I imagine.  If you use Roslyn then you're looking for compile time information on it or pre compile info in the ide but I'm not sure how that helps without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: I actually solved my problem on my own. I'll post the answer when I get back in the office. My need is to do this in a standalone program, not in VS. I'll give more details with my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

The solution is based on the "Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool" project template from Visual Studio.

As this template comes with solution opening and workspace creation, I'll skip this part.

```cs
private static async Task<List<INamedTypeSymbol>> GetDeclarationOfType(string typeName, Solution solution)
{
     var symbols = await SymbolFinder.FindSourceDeclarationsAsync(solution, x => x.Equals(typeName));
     return symbols.Where(x => x.Kind == SymbolKind.NamedType).Cast<INamedTypeSymbol>().ToList();
}
```

Here I simply use the `SymbolFinder` to find the declarations of the type I am looking for.

For each of the returned symbols, I then get the members (the methods then) of which name is my class name:

```cs
var members = symbol.GetMembers().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("MyMethod"));
```

For each of the matching members, I then get all of the references:

```cs
var references = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(member, solution);
```

The solution is partially based on [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/80ywpc/roslyn_how_to_get_parameter_information_for_a/) but I modified it to my needs.

So for each reference, I'll navigate the source tree until I find an invocation.
When I find one, I'll get the parameter I'm looking for (based on its index here) and if it's 'kind' is `SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression` then all I have what I need:

```cs
foreach (var referencedSymbol in references)
{
    foreach (var location in referencedSymbol.Locations)
    {
        var theToken = location.Location.SourceTree.GetRoot().FindToken(location.Location.SourceSpan.Start);
        var theNode = theToken.Parent;
        while (!theNode.IsKind(SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression))
        {
            theNode = theNode.Parent;
            if (theNode == null) break; // There isn't an InvocationExpression in this branch of the tree
        }

        if (theNode != null)
        {
            var argument = ((InvocationExpressionSyntax) theNode).ArgumentList.Arguments[searchPattern.ArgumentIndex];
            if (argument.Expression.IsKind(SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression))
            {
                textToTranslate.Add(argument.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `ToString()` on the argument itself returns the actual value of the argument, hence, the string value of the argument passed to the method.

For reference, my use case is to extract all translatable strings from my solution.
This is a very big solution (more than 170 projects) that uses 5 different ways to translate strings and I needed a way to find them all in the code automatically, in a tool that can be automated.

This might not be the best solution but I'll do at least for now.